# How do I track information about a button clicked on a website? (Selenium)

Tags: selenium

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox...

        var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");

        string text = ...
        IWebElement webElement = ...
```

After opening, the user does some manipulations, enters text, and presses a button.

Is it possible to track these actions using Selenium???
Maybe there are some other tools?

Comment: I'm not clear what your question is about. So selenium opens the browser, and then a real user intersects with the browser? Or do you want a way to record real user interactions so you can turn that into a test?

Comment: You have analytic tools for stats tracking and trafic on website. I do not see why you need to track button clicked in selenium. (loging, or write to file, consol can help, but that is not what you needs are)